# ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) HTTPError 403: *** does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build

I have a Github Action to submit my source-code to Google Cloud Build. The submission does work. The Cloud Build job is being triggered.

However the Github Action exits with an error. This is the error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) HTTPError 403: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>*** does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.</Details></Error>
```

I am using a custom service account. These are the roles I've assigned to it. I have no idea why the error is still thrown.

```
Cloud Build Service Account
Cloud Build Viewer
Environment User and Storage Object Viewer
Cloud Storage for Firebase Viewer
Storage Object Viewer
```

I read in another question that this issue has been solved by provided the role `Viewer` but a role just called `Viewer` does not exist - at least not in my role listing.

A little side question:

> Is there a way to check what role is needed for a given cloud action? For example seeing this in my logs `storage.objects.get` I'd like to see what roles do provide access to this.

Comment: `roles/viewer` is explained in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#basic-definitions).

Comment: Also you can see the role in the console [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles/details/roles<viewer).

Comment: @Jofre that was actually the solution! I do no understand what is happening. Why does it work with "Viewer" but not with "Storage Object Viewer" or even "Storage Admin" ? I can't grasp the concept behind that

Comment: I'm adding an answer with some info on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other question mentioned by the OP was referencing the role [`roles/viewer`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#basic-definitions), which is viewer in all resources for a project, rather than a more specific viewer role like [`roles/storage.objectViewer`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-storage-roles).

Note that the amount of permissions in each role is very different, and there might be a permission in the `roles/viewer` role that is not available in `roles/storage.objectViewer`, but it's needed for the build to work.

I'm guessing at some point the account tries to execute a [`buckets.get`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/get), and since `roles/storage.objectViewer` role does not have the explicit `storage.buckets.get` permission, it gives an access error. That permission is granted with the `roles/viewer` project role <sup>1</sup>.

In any way, the `roles/viewer` role can be found through the console [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles/details/roles%3Cviewer), or through the SDK with a command like this one:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding <YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT>@<YOUR_PROJECT>.iam.gserviceaccount.com --member='<YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT>@<YOUR_PROJECT>.iam.gserviceaccount.com' --role='roles/viewer'
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm just guessing, but the missing permission could be any other of the hundreds available to `roles/viewer` and missing from the other roles.

Answer (score 2):

On the IAM roles within GCP, ensure you have `storage.objects.get` added via `roles/storage.objectViewer` to the correct user/account.
You can find all IAM roles listed here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles

If all the roles check out, it's most likely an authentication issue with the service account and is simply authenticating with the old or incorrect credentials.

Comment: What do you mean by incorrect credentials? I am using the service account via Github Actions and using the service account key. I was not changing the key - and as I said the submission to cloud run works fine. How is it possible that just one thing can work here?

As you can see above I have set the "Storage Object Viewer" role. This should be sufficient right?

Answer (score 1):

For you side question, you can use [IAM Policy troubleshooter](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/troubleshooter) directly from the console. Set your principal (email), the resource and the permission. You will immediately know if it's OK or not.

However, as said by DIGI, I know you don't use the correct credential.